# knockout data-binding not working as expected with jquery

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I have an element that is data bound like this:

```
<input data-bind="value: observableCity" class="form-control" id="cityInput" type="text">
```

And another element like this:

```
<span class="" data-bind="text: observableCity"></span>
```

and some js that does this on an ajax call

```
$('#input1').val(data.City);
```

When I enter text into the `<input>` it is updated in the `<span>` as well, however, when i insert a value to the `<input>` using jquery it does not update in the `<span>` as well.  Is there a way to fix this that I missed?

Comment: you're not suposed to use any jquery selector in your js code once you've switched to ko. Simply modify the model (here the observableCity attribute in the model)  and any html view which are linked to the observable will be automagically updated as expected.

The overall goal of ko is to have a js code free of back-references to the html design structure. See, your $('input1') code will break when you'll modernize your site. And in real life, one changes likes 10 times the view layer for one change of the model layer.

Comment: yes, I didn't know how to use knockout when i asked this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to set the input's value via jQuery since such value will not be assigned to your observable variable, that's why your span doesn't reflect the input's value you just entered.

The observable's values are set by calling them as follows: `observableCity(data.City)`